# Best way to check if the document id is in an array in another document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check if a user on the app has been blocked. If they are, they won't be able to interact with the person that blocked them. I have something like this:

```
          ("qvaiFNKPXXQfEb3Q0p2kSgC24jG3" ==
             FirebaseFirestore.instance
             .collection('users')
              .where(FieldPath.documentId,
                isEqualTo: "vL66pzSX8ff17CYSLcrrlKbwWc42")
                .where("blockedUsers",
                  arrayContains: "qvaiFNKPXXQfEb3Q0p2kSgC24jG3")
                  .toString())
              ? Text('')
              : MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: addMessagingConversation,
                  child: Text(
                    'Message',
                   ),
                 ),
```

[image: image of firestore collection] - green is the id of the user that has been blocked by the user with the blue border around their id.

I'm just using these two IDs in the code for my example. In the example above `qvaiFNKPXXQfEb3Q0p2kSgC24jG3` is logged in and blocked by `vL66pzSX8ff17CYSLcrrlKbwWc42`

Am I even on the right path? New to flutter and firebase, so any opinions and advice is appreciated.

Comment: You could just read the document and examine the contents of the array in memory.  That's not going to be much more costly than a very narrow query for document id with an additional filter on it (except maybe if the total size of that document is very large, and you rarely expect this query to return a document).

Comment: Would it be possible to add to the statement above to either show a button or not? I kind of want to keep the statement above, or have something close to it. Example: if the user id isn't in the `blockedUsers` array, they can send a message, otherwise it'll just be a disabled button. I added a bit to the code in my initial question. Thank you.